# OpenGL Picking: How to avoid entities?

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, picking

I have a terrain and entities(npc, house...).

I'm able to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates with the `glReadPixels` function:

```
glReadPixels(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z);
// of course its not just that...
```

My character can move over that terrain without problem, but I'm not able to move when the mouse is over a big house and I try to move "behind" that house.

Do you know how I can avoid entities when converting screen coordinates to world coordinates ?

Comment: don't render the entities in the pass that creates that depth buffer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your depth buffer does not contain "entities". It contains the stuff you rendered. So if you read the depth buffer, you will read the depth for the closest stuff you rendered.

So either you make a special depth-only rendering pass that does not contain "entities", or you're going to have to do something else to convert from the user's selected location to a world-space position. And generally speaking, games use something else. Probably a ray-trace, but depending on the nature of your world, even that may not be necessary.